# How to install deprecated Firefox addon?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

Is there a way to install a deprecated addon in Firefox?

I remember doing it in Firefox 3 - can't remember how I did it exactly :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `extensions.check*` booleans to `about:config` in order for them to work.

[image]

In the above, moving from 3.X to 4.0 beta to 4.0 and then to an optimized version I compiled myself based on 4.2a I've gathered the above settings, I bet you need to add `extensions.checkCompatibility.4.0`.

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot - now I can install gleebox http://thegleebox.com/, can't live without that thing :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it'll work with FF4, but apparently with older versions it was a matter of 
going to about:config, finding extensions.checkCompatibility and setting its value to false.

Comment: extensions.checkCompatibility doesn't exist in FF4. Thx for the idea, though :)

Comment: @timmkl - It was never there by default.  You need to create it and set its value: `about:config | [RClick] New | Boolean`

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are asking about incompatible add ons.  If that's so.  Install [compatibility reporter firefox add on](http://reviewsmyfavourite.blogspot.com/2010/07/firefox-add-on-compatilbility-reporter.html) and install your Firefox add on.  Now it will be installed!!!

Answer (score 0):

While the currently accepted answer is still accurate, it has become a lot more cumbersome with the ever increasing number of newer versions of Firefox. Granted, Firefox handles compatibility better than it used to, and the need to force enable deprecated add-ons is less common. However, in case someone still needs to do this and finds this question, I'd like to give a more modern, easy-to-use answer.

Install the add-on [Disable Add-on Compatibility Checks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkcompatibility/). Then install your deprecated add-on. Before restarting Firefox, be sure that no add-ons you do not wish to use are turned on by checking the Addons panel. After restarting, see if the add-on works. If not, disable it again.

It is possible that Firefox will break in a way that you cannot get to the Addons panel and shut off the add-on. If so, close Firefox by using Alt-F4, wait for it to close completely, and then start it again in Safe mode by holding down shift while you click to open Firefox. Disable the addon in the Addons panel and then restart Firefox.